# Finding Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following matrix:

$$
A = \frac{1}{3}
\begin{bmatrix}
14 & -14 \\ -14 & 14
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I know that for finding eigen values I need to solve for $|A-\lambda I|=0$.

I found to solutions: $\lambda_1=\frac{28}{3},\lambda_2=0$.

And for finding eigen vectors I need to solve for $(A-\lambda I)v=0$ where $v=[x \ y]^T$

Looking only at $\lambda_1$ the solution I get from:

```
1/3 * [14 - 28/3, -14 - 28/3; -14 - 28/3, 14 - 28/3][x; y] = 0

x = -y -> v = [-y y] = [-1 1]
```

Now according to the solution that I have from my lecturer the solution is done with |lambda * I - A|

and then v = 1/sqrt(2) * [1 - 1].

My question is where does the 1/sqrt(2) came from ?

The picture of his solution is:

[image: Solution]

Comment: (+1) but next time please [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a normalization of the vector. The Eigen space is generated by $\left(\begin{matrix} 1\\-1\end{matrix}\right)$ (resp. $\left(\begin{matrix} 1\\1\end{matrix}\right)$) so it is generated by any non-zero vector in this line, in particular, the vector of norm $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$ i.e. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{matrix} 1\\-1\end{matrix}\right)$ (resp. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{matrix} 1\\1\end{matrix}\right)$)

Comment: Oh I understand now, thank you !

Comment: (+1) but "generated by any *nonzero* vector in this line"